# openid - splitting up request for two endpoints (c#)

Tags: c#, openid

how do you use [identitymodel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/overview.html) for c# to get a authorize code?
i need to make two seperate calls because the server infrastructure, one /auth and one /token, i have to work with apparently does not work with just one endpoint like google can do.

theres this:  [authorize url](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client/authorize.html)

but that only creates the request, im missing something like this for the authorize endpoint:

```
var client = new HttpClient();


var response = await client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
{
    Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",
    GrantType = "custom",

    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    Parameters =
    {
        { "custom_parameter", "custom value"},
        { "scope", "api1" }
    }
});
```

i did choose this library because it is shown [here](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) as certified.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to get the authorization code (using the authorization code flow) and you need to redirect the users browser to the **ru** variable as it is described [here](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client/authorize.html).

In theory, just a link pointing to that variable, like

```
<a href="[InsertRuVariableHere]">Login to IdentityServer</a>
```

In the response back you should eventually get back the authorization code. From that code you can then use IdentityModel to get the final tokens.